# Interesting sequences question Olympiad style

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, induction, contest-math

Let a sequence of *n* numbers be called *good* if there exists *2p* consecutive numbers somewhere in the sequence such that, of these *2p* numbers, each pair of numbers with distance *p* from each other are equal. (e.g. 1,3,2,4,3,2,4,6,7 - here, *p*=3 for the numbers 3,2,4,3,2,4)
Note that *p* is arbitrary. (By consecutive, I mean consecutive placings in the sequence.)

What is the least *n* such that the sequence of *n* numbers from the set `1,2,3,...,k`(allow repeats and exclusion of numbers) is not *good*, but its extension with an extra *n+1* th number is *good* for any *n+1* th number  from the set `1,2,3,...k`.

I have an idea like this:
...,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1. If you add 1 to the end, the last two numbers 1,1 make the sequence trivially *good*. If you add 2, then 1,2,1,2 makes the sequence *good*. If you carry on in this way, you get (2^k)-1. (This is probably not the least n, but it is an idea.)

Comment: Is a sequence good if _there exists a_ $p$ such that...? Or is it $p$-good if...? And $p$ is not restricted to primes?

Comment: if there exists some or a _p_, and not restriced to primes

Comment: Does extension mean we add the last number at the end?

Comment: Yes, we add any of 1,2,...,k to the end.